# Starting flask-socketio without POST errors

Tags: python-3.x, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, http-error

Hi (this is my first post, so I apologise for any errors in the post. I'd really appreciate it if you could point them out.)

I'm trying to familarize myself with flask-socketio and socket.io (using AWS C9 interface), but whenever I try to start the program using

```
flask run
```

in the terminal, and then open up the html document on the browser, I receive a list of errors (a mix of POST 400 and GET 400). I read on the flask-socketio docs that the flask server doesn't support web-sockets (which is what I want to use).

But, I've tried starting the program using

```
python application.py
```

(which is what some Youtube guides used, and worked), but I get a connection error when I try to open the html file on the browser at the url provided (which is different from the url provided when I run flask run).

eventlet and gevent, gevent-websocket are installed on the AWS workspace, as is flask-socketio. There is no difference in output between using app.run() and socketio.run(app).

The python code is:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
#need to create a secret key in order to use session -- so can keep data safe by encrypting using the key.
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "My secret!!"
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def a():
    return render_template("b.html")


@socketio.on("my event")
def received(data):
    print("msg:" + data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug = True)
```

The html doc:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src = "/static/tst.js"></script>



        <!--adding socketio connection-->
        <!-- from flask-socketio docs -->
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var socket = io();

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
            });
        </script>

        <title>
            Testing Testing 123
        </title>

    </head>

    <p id = "changer">Change Me!</p>
    <button onclick = "nxt()">Change the paragraph?</button>

    <p>Message:</p>
    <p id = "next">None</p>

</html>
```

The errors I receive using flask run:

```
"GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NBi-no4&sid=b44f8623ee1c40d5b6d6167413a1d078 HTTP/1.0" 400
"POST /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NBi-rFw&sid=f077028cc43c41229f8e4e72cc64bc30 HTTP/1.0" 400
```

Also, I noticed that application.py was using polling to send the data (&transport=polling) in the error, so I tried to force it to use websockets only by placing

```
socket.io.opts.transports = ['websocket']
```

right below the definition of var socket in the html doc, but that didn't work either. (Starting it with flask run still resulted in a slew of errors, and I still received a connection error from the browser using python application.py .)

Python Errors:

No apparent ones in terminal:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

Using curl to test connection:

On one terminal: `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:5000`

```
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
... 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

On terminal with application.py running:

```
(4760) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 40112)
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2020 00:42:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 341 0.001045
```

Any advice?

Comment: The correct way to start a Socket.IO application is by running the script itself. Please add details on the problem/errors you get when starting the application in this way. No point in going over the `flask run` problems, since that is an incorrect usage of Flask-SocketIO.

Comment: I have added some details about the python errors. Would you (or someone) mind taking another look? Thank you!

Comment: Are you running your server and firefox/chrome on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. If it helps, I also tested the connection with curl.